# Visual Studio Code 'Source Control' Incredibly Slow When Pushing/Pulling [Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS]

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

After adding a message and clicking on <Commit>, there's a loading bar that takes 1-2 minutes to push a change to my repository. It used to be instant.

Also, if I click on <Sync Changes> (screenshot below) after writing a message and adding a commit, I get an error in the Git log:

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

To get around the fatal error, I have to click on the 3-dot menu and click <Push>. Then <Sync Changes> goes away. I used to be able to click <Sync Changes> with no fatal error.

[image: vscode sync changes not working screenshot]

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.62.0

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.3 LTS

RAM: 16GB

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600

Extensions: One Dark Pro Atom Theme, Pylance and Python.

Comment: Check the Git output in the console panel.

Comment: What happens when you use Git directly? VS Code can't help if there's a problem in the local or remote Git repo. The screenshot shows that only a `git push` is being performed

Comment: Same here, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i realized when i have more than one project open in vscode that are binded to different repository, creates big waiting times. What i do is to close other projects and commit one project at a time. i hope it helps

**edit** :

Also when you do commit without commit, it can create bug in vscode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).